# No SDL event for space keypress if down+right or up+left already pressed

Tags: c, sdl

I am experimenting movements in a 2D game in SDL, and it works fine. However when I add the possibility for the character to shoot by pressing `SPACE`, I face a strange bug: If down and right keys or up and left keys are already pressed, no event is created when pressing `SPACE`. In other cases, an event is created, as it should be.

Here is the loop I use to get some events:

```
while (on == 1)
{
    SDL_PollEvent(&event);
    switch (event.type)
    {
        case SDL_KEYDOWN:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_ESCAPE:
                    on = 0;
                    break;
                case SDLK_UP:
                    shooter1.dir[0] = 1; // shooter1 is an instance of a structure that
                                         // contains a position and an array representing
                                         // 4 directions (down, up, left, right)
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    shooter1.dir[1] = 1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    shooter1.dir[2] = 1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    shooter1.dir[3] = 1;
                    break;
                case SDLK_SPACE:         // Eventually, the program does not go in this
                                         // case, even though the SPACE key is pressed
                    fprintf(stderr, "SPACE PRESSED\n");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        case SDL_KEYUP:
            switch (event.key.keysym.sym)
            {
                case SDLK_UP:
                    shooter1.dir[0] = 0;
                    break;
                case SDLK_DOWN:
                    shooter1.dir[1] = 0;
                    break;
                case SDLK_LEFT:
                    shooter1.dir[2] = 0;
                    break;
                case SDLK_RIGHT:
                    shooter1.dir[3] = 0;
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    event.type = 0;
    get_new_positions(&shooter1);
    SDL_BlitSurface(background, NULL, screen, &background_pos);
    blit_shooter(screen, &shooter1);
    SDL_Flip(screen);
}
```

Any idea of what this behavior is due to?

Comment: Silly question, but does this work in other applications? Not all keyboards can detect an arbitrary number of simultaneous keypresses -- if you see folks advertising a keyboard with "NKRO", that's what it's about. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)

Comment: If this is Linux, by the way, one way to answer the question with certainty is to parse evdev events coming from the input core (if you're on Linux) -- see the example code at https://python-evdev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I tried it with another program, which I wrote especially to study events, and the problem was there too, it was the same. Also, you are telling me that my computer may not be able to detect 3 keypresses at the same time? It is strange since in several applications I can use more than 3 keys at the same time. However I am not on Linux, unfortunately.

Comment: *Which* keys matters. Explicit modifier keys such as ctrl and alt often have special handling at the hardware level. Which platform are you on? Maybe we can try to find an equivalent test.

Comment: ...if this is a USB keyboard, you might try [USBpcap](http://desowin.org/usbpcap/) to look at which events are coming from the hardware. (Obviously, if there's no hardware event, there won't be anything you can do to fix the issue from software).

Comment: It is not, I use a laptop PC

Comment: Can you find a USB keyboard? Either it'll work, and that'll answer the question (as being about the hardware), or it won't, and you'll be able to sniff events to figure it out that way.

Comment: Interesting: I made a test in the game Minecraft. I assigned to the keys down and left some movements, and in game, when pressing both, my character was going backwards and on the left, but I could not jump (with space).

Comment: I don't have a USB keyboard

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is almost certainly a hardware limitation. Quoting from [the relevant Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key)), emphasis added:

> **Certain high-end keyboards have "n-key rollover".** This means that each key is scanned completely independently by the keyboard hardware, so that each keypress is correctly detected regardless of how many other keys are being pressed or held down at the time. [...]
>
> **However, to reduce cost and design complexity, most computer keyboards do not isolate all keys in this way. Instead, they use a matrix of key switches,** without any isolation diodes, **that assumes that only a limited number of keys will be held down at any given time.** With these keyboards, pressing as few as three keys can cause ghosting effects, although care is taken when laying out the matrix arrangement that this does not happen for common modifier key combinations.

Comment: The term "ghost" (written in the wikipedia page you shared) interested me so I searched on the Internet and found something that also helps alot understanding the problem I am facing: https://www.microsoft.com/appliedsciences/antighostingexplained.mspx